# jquery set ajax result to an outside variable callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I need to set a variable to the results of an ajax query. I realise that i cannot just return result in the success function as this is an asynchronous call. but would like to achieve this will a callback function and not set to a synchronous call.

I would like to achieve something like:

```
myMethod: function() {
   var result = function(callback) {
      this.getResults(params)
   }
},

getResults: function(params) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'some/url',
      data: params,
      success: function(data) {
         callback(data).call();
      }
   });
}
```

Where result = data

I know my syntax is not right, I have tried so many variations and havent found something that works. Any help would be soooooo appreciated. Thank-you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close. Pass the callback function to `getResults`.

```
myMethod: function() {
    this.getResults(params, callback);
},

getResults: function(params, callback) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'some/url',
      data: params,
      success: function(data) {
         callback(data);
      }
   });
}
```

Note that I removed the `var result =` since that's just not going to work given the asynchronicity you mentioned. If you need to perform further processing of `data`, it's got to happen in a callback.

Comment: Thanks! If i haven't allocated data to a variable in myMethod? Then how can i refer to it?

Comment: Sorry, did you mean `callback` instead of `data`? I don't understand.

Comment: Not sure ;)
I want a variable in myMethod to equal data. 
data is a json response and I want to loop through it and compare it to another variable i have set in myMethod.
Is that possible?

Comment: Ok. You can't do that, because of the asynchronous execution. Like I said in my answer, everything that relies on `data` must be passed as a callback (unless you're willing to accept synchronous execution, which you already said you're not). Take the logic that depends on `data` out of `myMethod` and put it into the `callback` function that you pass to `getResults`.

Comment: Okay. I think i may need to rethink what im trying to achieve here.
At least i know the syntax of a callback now ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.
I ended up getting rid of callback and just passed my variable from myMethod into the call to getResults and used that inside the success function.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try setting async to false?

```
myMethod: function() {
   var result = function(callback) {
      this.getResults(params)
   }
},

getResults: function(params) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      async:false, //<-- Here
      url: 'some/url',
      data: params,
      success: function(data) {
         callback(data).call();
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: *but would like to achieve this will a callback function and **not set to a synchronous call***.... and your code does not work (`callback` not defined, etc) don't just copy the OP's code.

Comment: The OP specifically said that they do not want to do this.