# Call ajax inside a custom method and return ajax result to called method

Tags: ajax, jquery

in my JSP I have link and button, for both I want to call Ajax action and use with result.

I am creating events for both link and button and calls Ajax. I need to return the result to the calling method.

```
//event for button
$(document).on('click', ".addComponent", function(){
        var htmlContent=$(this).html();
        $('.addComponent').html('Loading...').fadeIn();
        var urlAction=$(this).attr("id");
        var dataFields=$(this).data('val');
        var data=callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields); //data not returning from ajax
        var ajaxActionResult=ajaxResult(data);
        $('.addComponent').html(htmlContent).fadeIn();
        $('#popUpForm').html(ajaxActionResult);
        $('#popUpForm').dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

//event for link
$(document).on('click', "#dimComponentList >TBODY > TR > TD > a", function(){
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        var urlAction=$(this).attr("href");
        var dataFields="";
        var data=callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields);
        var ajaxActionResult=ajaxResult(data); //ajax not returning data
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
        $('#applicationList').html(ajaxActionResult);
        return false;
     });
```

Here is my method to call Ajax

```
function callActionUsingAjax(urlAction,datafields)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: urlAction,
            data: datafields,
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
```

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344683/jquery-set-ajax-result-to-an-outside-variable-callback) but I don't know how to use call back on my custom method like that. There are some other events also I need to call this Ajax. That's why I used Ajax inside a custom method.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax call is asynchronous and takes its time to complete, while the execution goes on and that's why you don't have any data in the "return".

You need to pass a callback function to your `callActionUsingAjax` and call it in your `success` handler (or complete or error that depends on the logic.

Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".addComponent", function(){
    //... other stuff
    callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, dataFields, function (data) { //this is tha callback (third argument)
        var ajaxActionResult=ajaxResult(data);
        $('.addComponent').html(htmlContent).fadeIn();
        $('#popUpForm').html(ajaxActionResult);
        $('#popUpForm').dialog("open");
        // all of the above happens when ajax completes, not immediately.
    }); 

    return false;
});

function callActionUsingAjax(urlAction, datafields, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: urlAction,
        data: datafields,
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```